# OnLongClickListener - play() music - return stop()

Tags: android, audio-player, onlongclicklistener, android-music-player

i'm trying to implement OnLongClickListener on MediaPlayer, but i can't figure out how can i manage on Release button to stop music.

This is the code which i have now.

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.play) {
                mp1.setLooping(true);
                mp1.start();             }
                                                         } 
     else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.play) {
                if (mp1 != null) {
                    mp1.setLooping(false);
                    mp1.pause(); 
                    mp1 = null;
                }

}    }

        return false; }
```

but it gives me error **The method onLongClick(View, MotionEvent) of type MainActivity must override or implement a supertype method**
i managed the music to play on long click but on release false or true it didn't stopped the music... how can i manage it ...

Comment: The error means that you are trying to override a method that does not exits (or can not be override) in the super class. `Activity` has not `onLongClick`.

Comment: I dont think you can implement onLongClicklistener on MediaPlayer.You can implement it on some view.Implement it for some view like button etc

Comment: Are you trying to do pause/resume or stop/play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i made it to work with onTouch method, it works one time, but on the second click i get nullpointerexception

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.play) {
            mp1.setLooping(true);
            mp1.start(); 
        }
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.play) {
            if (mp1 != null) {
                mp1.setLooping(false);
                mp1.pause(); 
                mp1 = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
} }
```

here is the error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   app.technozed.dogwhistle.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:68) at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3762) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:863) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1731)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1120)
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1715)
>   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1787) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

i think it's because on Pause i set mp1=null; isn't it?

yes it is, i just deleted mp1=null; and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, it is because mp1 is null. You are not initializing it after setting it to null on ACTION_UP.

Comment: Are you trying to do pause/resume or stop/play?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will stop your player imidiatly after starting because both action (Action Down and Action Up) are fired respectively on touch down and release.

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.play) {
               if(mp1!=null && mp1.isPlaying())
                mp1.setLooping(false);
                    mp1.pause(); 
                    mp1 = null;

              }else{
                // initialize mp1 ... Initialize your player here
                //
                mp1.setLooping(true);
                mp1.start(); 

           }
       }
      return false;   
}
```

Comment: it doesn't even play.

Comment: You did not paste your code which initialize your player, So I add a comment on that place.Initialize your player here :  // initialize mp1 ...

Comment: i initialized the player in onCreate, after this i have 5 buttons which loads 5 different songs and after all this i have 1 play button with onLongClickListener.

Comment: Will be more helpful if you can put your complete code.